# Initialising values inside structure

Tags: structure

When I compiled the below code in gcc I get 1408.How does it work.Can we initialise values inside structure?

```
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    struct Test { 
    int i=1408; 
    };
    int main() 
    { 
    Test l;     
    int p=1508;     
    l.i==p;     
    cout<<l.i; 
    }
```

Comment: Please format your code. That's very hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

`l.i==p;` does nothing. `==` tests if two things are equal to each other. That's not an assignment.

You must have meant

```
l.i=p;
```

Comment: Can we initialize value inside struct

Comment: @SoundaryaSivaraman Should be able to. The reason you're seeing the results you are though is because you never changed `i` after you initialized it.

Answer (score 0):

It is best to declare structure variable in struct body and intialise values using objects created using structure  identifiers in your code identifier is Test.

Initialisation can be in the form of
Test t1 ={ 1408 };

Comment: Why doesnt it throw an error when i assigned directly?

Comment: Do you use c or c++? Its legal in c++ 11, and it means that this value gets used for constructors (unless those  explicitly do something else)

Comment: Never mind, you use a c++ header. Read http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members